# How to use XML Schema 1.1 in WSDL file?

Tags: xml, soap, xsd, wsdl, schema

I have an existing XML schema (not made by me) which perfectly validates (e. g. using Oxygen XML Developer). It is using XML Schema 1.1 features and therefore defines `vc:minVersion="1.1" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"`.

However, as soon as I embed (copy into, *not* include/reference) this into a WSDL file, it will get invalid in Oxygen XML Developer. Once I change `vc:minVersion="1.1"` to `vc:minVersion="1.0"` in the WSDL file, it will validate, given I also correct the now invalid 1.1 features.

To be precise, this super simple WSDL will validate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://some.location.tld" xmlns:tns="http://some.location.tld" xmlns:objects="http://www.domain.tld" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.domain.tld" vc:minVersion="1.0" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:element name="foobar" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="someRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="objects:foobar"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="someResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="objects:foobar"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="somePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="get">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:someRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:someResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="someSoapHttpBinding" type="tns:somePortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="get">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="some">
        <wsdl:port name="somePort" binding="tns:someSoapHttpBinding">
            <soap:address location="https://some.location.tld"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

And once you only change `vc:minVersion="1.0"` to `vc:minVersion="1.1"` it will turn invalid.

So the question is, how do I correctly define a WSDL containing an embedded XSD 1.1 schema? Is this a bug in Oxygen XML Developer (version 17)? Which tools should support it? Maybe Altova XMLSpy?

Do I maybe have to use WSDL 2.0 to make use of embeded XSD 1.1 schemas? At least `gsoap` mentions on their homepage that XSD 1.1 is fully supported - this must mean that WSDLs with XSD 1.1 can exist.

***help***

[edit] To clarify: Simply using XML Schema 1.0 and workarounding the 1.1 features is *not* an option.

Comment: I know this is rather old, but have you tried moving the `xmlns:vs` schema reference to the root element?